# Having trouble centering headings on page

Tags: html, css

I have some page headings on my website but they seem to often become slightly off centre and I don't seem to be able to easily centre them.

[image]

As you can see by looking at the small semi-circle above in the logo, the ABOUT ME heading is not completely in the centre of the page.

I would very much appreciate it if anyone could assist me with putting these headers in the middle of the page.

Current CSS

```
#navigationBar
{
width:75%;
height:35px;
margin:10px auto;
padding: 0 5px;
border:0px solid #1e1e1e;
background-color: #f3f3f3;
}


#nav 
{
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: auto;
margin-top:8px;
padding: 0;
background-color: #f3f3f3;
text-align: center;
color:#1e1e1e;
font-family:gobold;
text-align:center;
font-style:none;
font-weight: 100
}

#nav span a 
{
padding-right:5%;
padding-left:5%;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
color:#1e1e1e; 
}

#nav span a:hover 
{
color:#d21a20;
}
```

Current HTML

```
<div id="navigationBar">
<div id="nav">
    <span><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></span>
    <span><a href="about.html">about me</a></span>
    <span><a href="contact.html">contact</a></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that this is happening, is because your `spans` are all different `widths`, because their `widths` are being set by how long the text inside the `a` tags are. For example, "portfolio" is a little longer than "contact", so it's offsetting "about me" just a little bit.

Make your `a` tags all the same `width` by setting `a` with `display: inline-block` and give it a `width` like `width: 100px`, or whatever looks best for you.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8mT3g/